# Here maps policy on using screeshots and generating higher resolution printable map images combining screenshots

Tags: maps, here-api, policy

I am developing an application where having a proper printable map image could be more beneficial; I have been through developer policy and guidelines but were unable to find anything specific about conditions on use of screenshots where I would like my application to be able to **generate higher resolution printable map images** may or may not be **combining screenshots** as necessary only if it's allowed.

*How do I get content usage policies* of here maps on screenshot assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check our location content terms [here](https://legal.here.com/en-gb/terms/general-content-supplier-terms-and-notices)

> If your products and/or services use map data that is made accessible through the HERE Services, you shall provide End-Users of your products and/or services with notice, in a reasonably conspicuous manner (e.g., in the End-User Terms), of the supplier notices and related terms applicable to such map data by (i) referencing the notices and related terms set forth herein, and (ii) including the following copyright notice:  “© 1987 - 2020 HERE. All rights reserved.”
>
> Data for countries in the Americas, the Middle East, Europe, Russia, Africa and/or Asia Pacific: © 1987 - 2020 HERE
>
> The following terms shall apply to the use of map data for the countries specified below to the extent that (i) the application, product and/or service which you are using; or (ii) your product and/or services uses or includes map data for each respective country."

Regarding to printable map images or screenshots, please try;

1. adding copyright notice
2. checking country specific requirement. For example in EU, map content in digital formats providing to end users is allowed (for example in pdf format), as long as you don't print out the map images directly and provide to the end users.